# Why do we sometimes insert prepositions when making Vorgangspassiv and sometimes not?

Tags: preposition, grammar-identification, passive

In my german class, we were taught that, when making Passiv, we use these prepositions

> Agens -
>
> von: Personen, Institutitionen , (Naturkräfte)
>
> durch: Vermittler, Mittel, Abstrakta

However, I notice that we do away with the prepositions sometimes. For example, consider this sentence converted to Vorgangspassiv:

> Heute kann man fast alles über das Internet bestellen

> Heute kann fast alles über das Internet bestellt werden.

Why is it that sometimes we introduce a preposition, and other times not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepositions like "durch" and "von" are usually inserted in passive sentences to connect the actor (the subject in the active sentence) with the action.

In your specific sentence, there simply is no preposition because there is no actor that needs to be connected. (The "man" vanishes in the passive sentence)

Comment: A more or less over-correct agent specification would be: _Heute kann von einem fast alles über das Internet bestellt werden._ Besser: _Heute kann von jedem fast alles über das Internet bestellt werden._ But the crucial point in using the passive voice is that the agent is not necessarily mentioned explicitly - as in this sentence.